# Remote EJB call class not found exception

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to play around with EJB remote call but I'm getting an error. I have a web app called `CallerApp` that calls a method in another web app called `RecieverApp`.

In the `CallerApp` I have a remote interface:

```
@Remote
public interface ControllerRemote {
    public int perform(int i);
}
```

and the call is performed in this class:

```
public class Talker {

   @EJB private ControllerRemote remote;

   //constructor and invoke setRemote() method to set remote

   private void setRemote() throws Exception{
        Properties p = new Properties();
        Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(p);
        Object ref = jndiContext.lookup("java:global/RecieverApp/Controller!bean.ControllerRemote");
        remote = (ControllerRemote) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ref, ControllerRemote.class);
   }

 public void action(){
      remote.perform(5);
 }

}
```

RecieverApp is depoloyed on the same Glassfish server:

```
@Stateless
public class Controller implements Serializable, ControllerRemote{


   @Override
   public int perform(int i){
      //return something
   }
}
```

The interface in RecieverApp is exactly as the one in CallerApp:

```
@Remote
public interface CallerRemote{

   public int perform(int i);

}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
SEVERE: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/RecieverApp/Controller!bean.ControllerRemote'
   in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
[Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: ejb ref resolution error for remote business interfacebean.ControllerRemote
[Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bean.ControllerRemote]]
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

PS: I'm using Glassfish 3.1 and both applications are deployed on the same server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few things to consider:

- check whether JNDI name *java:global/RecieverApp/Controller!bean.ControllerRemote* exists, there was nice JNDI browser in Glassfish 2.x, but they didn't put it in GF 3 (it [should be](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-5842) in GF 4), but you still have good old command line: `asadmin list-jndi-entries`
- check whether your `CallerRemote` interfaces are in same packages in both applications
- there is no need to perform both injection (`@EJB`) and JNDI lookup, if your class `Talker` is container-managed (i.e. bean, servlet, etc.) then `@EJB` annotation will suffice, otherwise use only lookup

Comment: Perfect!! it was package naming as u suggested in point#2. I had different package naming for the interfaces. Thanks alot :)